# C++ std::string::at throwing std::out_of_range

Tags: c++, string, c++11, stdstring

```
void Display::displayText(const char* text) {
    using std::string;
    using std::vector;
    string line = string(text);
    vector<string> temp(1);
    if (Display::startLine < 0) Display::startLine = 0;
    bool cont = true;
    int lastRegex = 0;
    int regex = 1;
    string tmp = string(" ");
    for (int i=0; i<line.length(); i++) {
        if(line.at(i)=='\n') {
            tmp = line.substr(lastRegex, i-lastRegex);
            tmp.erase(tmp.find("\n"), tmp.find("\n"));
            lastRegex = i+1;
            regex++;
            temp.resize(regex);
            temp[regex-1] = tmp;
        }
        if (i - lastRegex == COLS-3) {
            bool b = true;
            int j = i;
            while (b) {
                if (line.at(i) == ' ') {
                    b = false;
                    tmp = line.substr(lastRegex, j-lastRegex);
                    lastRegex = j+1;
                    regex++;
                    temp.resize(regex);
                    temp[regex-1] = tmp;
                }
                j--;
            }
        }
    }
    regex++;
    temp.resize(regex);
    temp[regex-1] = line.substr(lastRegex, string::npos);

    if (Display::startLine+1 > temp.size()) Display::startLine = temp.size()-1;
    for (int i=0; i<temp[startLine].length(); i++) Window::draw(i+1, 1, temp[Display::startLine].at(i));
        if (Display::startLine+1 <= temp.size()-1)
            for (int i=0; i<temp[Display::startLine+1].length(); i++) Window::draw(i+1, 2,                 temp[Display::startLine].at(i));
        if (Display::startLine > 0) Window::draw(COLS-2, 1, '^');
        if (Display::startLine + 1 < temp.size()-1) Window::draw(COLS-2, 2, 'v');
    }
}
```

This code compiles correctly.  When I run it, however, I get an `std::out_of_range` error for `std::basic_string::at`.

I have tried to add a check for if line is empty, and change the for loop so it is `.length()-1`, but both of those produce the same result.

This function is supposed to take in the text, and display it on the top two lines of a window, (thus the COLS variable and the `Window::draw`) and add arrows to the end of the lines if the text expands past the two lines. The text I'm inputting currently that throws the error is "Hello World!".

It isn't a problem with the draw function, if I manually display the same text with `Window::draw`. (This method is specifically made to automatically wrap the text around the screen and cap it at two lines)

Comment: We are not a replacement for your debugger :/

Comment: [std::out_of_range](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/out_of_range) - this means you access non-existent array element with `.at()`

Comment: In stead of using `for (int i=0; i<line.length(); i++)` prefer to use `for(auto ch; line)`.

Comment: @RSahu I need to have the i for use with getting the correct substrings

Comment: In that case, you can define and initialize `i` before the loop and use `for ( auto it = line.begin(); it != line.end(); ++it, ++i )`.

Comment: When doing that g++ throws erros about 'it' not naming a type

Comment: Adding a check if `j` is within the correct value before trying to get `line.at(j)` does nothing. (Check was `if (j > -1 && j < line.length())`)

Answer (score 1):

Strings are arrays of characters that are indexed starting at 0. If you want to access the first character, its at position 0, if you want to access the last character, its at position length -1.

For example, string test = "hello";

test.at(0) would give me 'h', test.at(4) would give me '0', test.at(5) = test.at( test.length() ) = out of range error

Change your for loop to

```
  for (int i=0; i<line.length() - 1; i++) {
```

Comment: the last i will be line.length()-2 in this case

Comment: Both -1 and -2 didn't work.  But, wouldn't < line.length() be sufficient, because i goes up to one less than the length of line, (i=line.length()-1 would still be less than line.length()), so the position at .length()-1 should still be valid, then, it adds 1 to i, and then i is equal to line.length(), so i !< line.length(), so that for loop doesn't execute, so it never calls line[line.length()], the highest it will go to is line[line.length()-1].

Comment: As to why the code is still failing, I don't have any updates, but in regards to the for loop, consider a for loop with the constraint i < length.  Let length = 5, when i = 4, we check our conditions, i is still less then length, so we increment.  i is now 5 and we proceed with the contents of the for loop.  Next time we check our conditions, we fail.  Try a simple test: for(i = 0, i < 5; ++i) cout << i ;

Comment: I tested the code:
    'string str("Hello"); for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++) cout << str[i];` in a seperate project just containing that with what it required to compile, and no errors were thrown, so it isn't the way my for loop is structured.

Comment: Wow, you are absolutely correct, I don't know what I was thinking!  I will go back and see if I find anything else in your code.

Comment: I discovered if I commented out the entire for loop, the error persisted.  It turned out to be that I was assigning `regex = 1` instead of `=0`